# Replacing THC/THC.h module to ATen/ATen.h module

Tags: c++, pytorch

I have question about replacing <THC/THC.h> method.
Recently, I'm working on installing different loss functions compiled with cpp and cuda.
However, what I faced was a fatal error of

```
'THC/THC.h': No such file or directory
```

I found out that TH(C) methods were currently deprecated in recent version of pytorch, and was replaced by ATen API (https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/question-about-thc-thc-h/147145/8).

For sure, downgrading my pytorch version will solve the problem. However, due to my GPU compatibility issue, I have no choice but to modify the script by myself. Therefore, my question can be summarized into follows.

**First,** how can I replace codes that have dependency of TH(C) method using ATen API?. Below are codes that I have to modify, replacing those three lines looked enough for my case.

```
#include <THC/THC.h>
extern THCState *state;
cudaStream_t stream = THCState_getCurrentStream(state);
```

**Second**, will single modification on cpp file be enough to clear the issue that I'm facing right now? (*This is just a minor question, answer on first question will suffice me*).

For reference, I attach the github link of the file I'm trying to build (https://github.com/sshaoshuai/Pointnet2.PyTorch).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After struggling for a while, I found the answer for my own.
In case of  `THCState_getCurrentStream`, it could directly be replaced by `at::cuda::getCurrentCUDAStream()`. Therefore, modified code block was formulated as below.

```
//Comment Out
//#include <THE/THC.h>
//extern THCState *state;
//cudaStream_t stream = THCState_getCurrentStream(state);

//Replace with
#include <ATen/cuda/CUDAContext.h>
#include <ATen/cuda/CUDAEvent.h>
cudaStream_t stream = at::cuda::getCurrentCUDAStream();
```

After replacing the whole source code, I was able to successfully build the module.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have the same problem as you. I have to convert `THCCeilDiv` `THCudaCheck` and `THCudaFree`. Is there any documentation or a resource to help me do the conversion?

Comment: `THCCeilDiv` can be replaced by `common.hpp` and `THCudaCheck` can be replaced by `AT_CUDA_CHECK` (https://github.com/CoinCheung/pytorch-loss/pull/37). I have no idea about `THCudaFree`. Maybe you can search through github repos with keyword THC.

Comment: Having a similar problem trying to install DCNv2 getting error of `TH.h` not found. in my case the code uses `THArgCheck`  Is there anything I look into to know how to replace things?

Comment: @rram12 do #include <ATen/ceil_div.h> and the replace THCCeilDiv with at::ceil_div because ceil_div uses the at namespace

Comment: Check out this GitHub issue [#72807](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/72807#issuecomment-1699371013) for `THCCeilDiv`, `THCudaCheck`, `THCudaFree`, and `THCudaMalloc`